# HandleErrorAttribute is not working in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make HandleErrorAttribut working in ASP.NET MVC 5 but it's not working

I created FilterConfig.cs file under App_Start

```
namespace WebApplication12.App_Start
{
    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }
    }
}
```

and in Global.asax

```
namespace WebApplication12
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {



        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        }

    }
}
```

and in web.config

```
  <system.web>
     <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Errorrr.cshtml">
       </customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
```

And still get errors and can't handle exceptions

```
  [HandleError]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            throw new Exception("New Error");
 }
```

Thank you,

Lucia

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `HandleError` Attribute will display the `Error` view located in the `~/Views/Shared` folder but if you wanted to display a specific view you can set the View property of the attribute.

```
[HandleError(View = "Error")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
    int u = Convert.ToInt32("");// Error line
    return View();
}
```

See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If its Mvc5 make sure you use "using System.Web.Mvc" and not "using System.Web.Http.Filters"  as the latter is  for WebApi. Also can you post the code for HandleErrorAttribute class.